# How to see the SOAP request and response generated for my Java program

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have created a Java web-service and its client program by following an example that uses JAX-WS.

My Service program:

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import java.util.Random;

@WebService
public interface RandService {
    @WebMethod
    public int next1();

    @WebMethod
    public int[] nextN(final int n);
}
```

/

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import java.util.Random;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "rand2.RandService")
public class RandImpl implements RandService {
    private static final int maxRands = 16;

    @WebMethod
    public int next1() {
        return new Random().nextInt();
    }

    @WebMethod
    public int[] nextN(final int n) {
        final int k = (n > maxRands) ? maxRands : Math.abs(n);
        int[] rands = new int[k];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            rands[i] = r.nextInt();
        return rands;
    }
}
```

and this is my client program:

```
import client.RandServiceService;
import client.RandService;
import java.util.List;

public class RandClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // set-up
        RandServiceService service = new RandServiceService();
        RandService port = service.getRandServicePort();
        // sample calls
        System.out.println(port.next1());
        System.out.println();
        List<Integer> nums = port.nextN(4);
        for (Integer num : nums)
            System.out.println(num);
    }
}
```

The program is running fine, but how can I see the SOAP request and SOAP response that are generated internally for my program? Please help me in how to get those details.

Comment: use fiddler, it is very helpful

Comment: @T McKeown, Thanks for suggesting Fiddler, but when I run my client program I am not able to see the SOAP request that is generated internally. Where as if I access any other URL using my browser then fiddler is able to capture the data.

Comment: you have to point your app at fiddler, and let fiddler point to real target.

Comment: I am using eclipse for running this program, can you please let me know how to do the configuration so my program request/response in eclipse IDE are captured by fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

Use [tcpmon](http://ws.apache.org/tcpmon/tcpmontutorial.html), although no longer supported

Comment: Thanks robermann, I am not able to download the binary disctribution of tcpmon software, looks like we cannot download it now.

Comment: I downloaded it and ran the tcpmon, but when I ran my client program, I am not able to see any progress on tcpmon. Is there anything that I am missing here?

Comment: Tcpmon runs as a "man in the middle" between your client and the server: have you set a tcp port were it can listen your request and then (after having dumped it) redirect it to the server's tcp port?

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI is the daddy of ws testing. http://www.soapui.org.

Comment: Thanks Ove, but I am interested to see the SOAP request and response generated internally by my Java program.

Comment: @Ove AFAIK the real daddy in the Java world is tcpmon :)

Answer (score 0):

The [SoapUI OpenSource (free)](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html) will show you the SOAP XML for both the client and the server side.  With this tool you will absolutely see the response SOAP XML from the server side.  Download the zip archive version if you just want to try it out.  (I launch the ZIP version of SoapUI by setting JAVA_HOME and clicking on SoapUI/bin/soapui.bat

Here is a quick start to see your web service in action..

```
 1. Open SoapUI
 2. Create a Project

 3. Provide the path to your WSDL file. (If well-formed you will see the operations in your new project a tree control).

 4. Open the tree node to an operation and create a SoapUI request template
        a. Select the operation
                1) Right->Click "New Request" 
        b. Name the Request (new node for Request appears in tree)
 5. Run a test for your operation.
        a. Use the property editor below the tree
                1) Provide any arguments 
                2) Provide any authentication
        b. Right-Click on the Request
                1) "Show Request Editor"
  5. Ponder your SOAP request envelope XML (on left)
  6. Click on the run arrow
        a. Ponder your SOAP response (on right)
```

[image]